# Changing Score in AndEngine Dynamically Like other games

Tags: android, andengine

I don't know the exact term for what I am looking for.
I am developing a game and I am showing score in other game scene. I want to change the score (Actually add current score in previous score) in such a way that is change one by one like in other games.
For example if previous score in 10 and current score is 10 then I want to show it like this with speed 10 11 12 13 14 15... while adding. And when reached 20 a sound will be played like tiiiinnnnnnnn. I want to add one by one.
I hope I cleared my question please provide a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way that works for me.

```java
private TimerHandler timerHandler;
private long startTime = 120000; // 2 minutes for example

private void createTimer() {
    final float period = 1; //one second

    this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(timerHandler = new TimerHandler(period, new ITimerCallback() {                      
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            timerHandler.reset();

            startTime = (long) (startTime - (period * 1000));
            int seconds = (int) ((startTime / 1000) % 60);
            int minutes = (int) ((startTime / 1000) / 60);
            timerText.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));                            
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Use Changeable text for your purpose,

```
ChangeableText textTime = new ChangeableText(int xPosition, int yPosition, Font mFont, "00");
```

then start a timer and give it delay for the speed you want to for changing

Now suppose you want to change your text from

int x = 10 to int y = 20

```
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                x++;
                textTime.setText(tm);
                if(x==y) {
                     timer.cancel();
                }
            }

    }, 0, 100); // you can change this delay with your own
```